# Select picture and send form

Tags: php, html

I'm working on some personal projects, and today I just can't wrap my head around how to do one thing.

I have form, where is one input box and under I want to add bunch of thumbnails from which can user select from. and than He can hit Submit button and it will get processed by ajax depending on the input.

Now I have just classical select with options ( which is a text ) and that part I would like to replace with pictures, so user select picture and it will post a value of that picture or ID..

How would I go about to do it, logically ? ( I might not making much sense, I'm quite tired now :) ) I have the form working, ajax also, just can't figure out how to use picture as checkbox or something like that...

But any helpful comment is welcome.

Comment: store the value in a js var or set a hidden input and change that value on selecting an image. dont think of the images as checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it with standard HTML and CSS, a `<select>` can only have text for its options. You can, however, implement a control that mimics a `<select>` dropdown in javascript or, I'd suggest, forego the work and use something like a ready-made jQuery plugin, for example, [this](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) or something from [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/).